# Dlookup string failing

Tags: ms-access-2013

For some reason i can't get the dlookup to function correctly i keep getting errors. The error for this is data type mismatch.

```
  Option Compare Database
  Private Sub Command131_Click()
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  If (Nz(DLookup("LetterSent1Bool", "dbo_T_Volunteers", _
 "VolunteerID = '" & Me![VolunteerID] & "'"))) > 0 Then

 MsgBox "ERROR !     This Volunteer has already received this Letter ,"
 Else

 DoCmd.OpenQuery "ProduceLettersSixToTwelve", , acReadOnly
 If DCount("*", "dbo_T_SixToTwelveWeeks") > 0 Then

 MsgBox "SUCCESS !    Please Open The Mail Merge Template"

 Else
 MsgBox "ERROR !     No Records Found"
 End If
 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, i need to remove quotes around     & Me![VolunteerID]

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Command131_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
If (Nz(DLookup("LetterSent1Bool", "dbo_T_Volunteers", _
"VolunteerID = " & Me![VolunteerID]))) > 0 Then

MsgBox "ERROR !     This Volunteer has already received this Letter ,"
Else

DoCmd.OpenQuery "ProduceLettersSixToTwelve", , acReadOnly
If DCount("*", "dbo_T_SixToTwelveWeeks") > 0 Then

 MsgBox "SUCCESS !    Please Open The Mail Merge Template"

 Else
 MsgBox "ERROR !     No Records Found"
  End If
 End If
 End Sub
```